# Artifacts in frames FireMonkey Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am using RAD 11.2 to make an application on FireMoneky. I use frames in my application, and when I load them, a border appears on my buttons, tables, and other elements that are not in the styles.

As an example:

- [I'm just activating the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHnPz.png)
- [The state of the components returns to normal as soon as I change the size of the application, or switch tabs on the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3JSh.png)

The problem occurs on almost all components that are in the frame until I either switch the tab or resize the form. Moreover, their behavior is sometimes not at all adequate, for example, the table that is shown in the second image in a normal state sometimes begins to produce a lot of cells, as soon as you click on any of them, it comes back to normal.

I tried to do a repaint of components, forms, frames, but it didn't help. In fact, it felt like it didn't react at all.

The code of the main form where the frame is loaded:

```
unit UMain;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Objects,
  System.ImageList, FMX.ImgList, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.TabControl, FMX.Layouts, FMX.Calendar, FMX.Maps, FMX.TreeView;

type
  TacFrame = class of TFrame;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    RContainer: TRectangle;
    RMenu: TRectangle;
    blue_pit: TBrushObject;
    RInsideContainer: TRectangle;
    BExit: TCornerButton;
    CornerButton2: TCornerButton;
    BObjects: TCornerButton;
    ImageList1: TImageList;
    StyleBook1: TStyleBook;
    brush_pink: TBrushObject;
    ver_ter: TBrushObject;
    Oreng: TBrushObject;
    Gris: TBrushObject;
    RHeader: TRectangle;
    RUserInfo: TRectangle;
    CAvatar: TCircle;
    RUsername: TRectangle;
    TUsername: TText;
    MapView1: TMapView;

    procedure BExitClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);

    procedure RectResize(Sender:TObject; Revert: Boolean = False);
    procedure CAvatarMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure CAvatarMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure RMenuMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
    procedure Text4Resize(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FActiveRect: TRectangle;
    procedure OpenFrame(btn : TButton);
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TCmpData = record
    Caption: string;
    FrameType: TacFrame;
    RectName: string;
  end;

  TCmpsArray = array [0..6] of TCmpData;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  ActiveMenuRect: TRectangle;
  CurrentWorkFrame: TFrame;

implementation

uses UObjects,USystems,UDashboard,USettings,UWelcome,UJournals,UUpdates;
{$R *.fmx}
{$R *.Windows.fmx MSWINDOWS}
{$R *.iPhone47in.fmx IOS}
{$R *.SSW3.fmx ANDROID}
{$R *.Surface.fmx MSWINDOWS}

procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(ActiveMenuRect) then ActiveMenuRect.Visible:=False;
  OpenFrame(TButton(Sender));
  RectResize(ActiveMenuRect);
end;

procedure TForm1.CAvatarMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
var this: TCircle;
begin
  this:=TCircle(Sender);

end;

procedure TForm1.CAvatarMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
var this: TCircle;
begin
  this:=TCircle(Sender);
end;

procedure TForm1.BExitClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.Terminate;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   TUsername.Text:='Зубенко Михаил Петрович';
   RUsername.Width:= TUsername.Text.Length+TUsername.Width+RUsername.Width;
end;

const
  Cmps: TCmpsArray = (
     (Caption: 'Объекты';    // 0
     FrameType: TFObjects;
     RectName: 'RObjectsHint'),

     (Caption: 'Системы';    // 1
     FrameType: TSystems;
     RectName: 'RSystemsHint'),

     (Caption: 'Журналы';    // 2
     FrameType: TJournals;
     RectName: 'RJournalsHint'),

     (Caption: 'Дашбоард';   // 3
     FrameType: TDashboard;
     RectName: 'RStatisticHint'),

     (Caption: 'Обновления';   // 4
     FrameType: TUpdates;
     RectName: 'RStatisticHint'),

     (Caption: 'Настройки';    // 5
     FrameType: TSettings;
     RectName: 'RObjectsHint'),

     (Caption: 'Приветствие'; // 6
     FrameType: TWelcome;
     RectName: 'RObjectsHint')

     );

procedure TForm1.OpenFrame(btn : TButton);
var
  OldFrame: TFrame;
  i: integer;
begin


 if not (CurrentWorkFrame is Cmps[Btn.Tag].FrameType) then
  OldFrame := CurrentWorkFrame;

  if OldFrame <> nil then begin
    FreeAndNil(OldFrame);
  end;

  CurrentWorkFrame := Cmps[Btn.Tag].FrameType.Create(Application);
  CurrentWorkFrame.Parent:=RInsideContainer;

end;

procedure TForm1.RMenuMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  self.StartWindowDrag;
end;

procedure TForm1.RectResize(Sender: TObject; Revert: Boolean);
var this: TRectangle;
    i: integer;
begin
  if Assigned(Sender) then begin
   this:=TRectangle(Sender);
    if Revert = False then
     this.AnimateFloat('Opacity', 1, 0.5)
    else
      this.AnimateFloat('Opacity', 0, 0.15)
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.Text4Resize(Sender: TObject);
var this: TText;
begin
  this:=TText(Sender);
  if this.Width<190 then
  begin
   this.AnimateFloat('Opacity', 0, 0.5)
  end
  else
    this.AnimateFloat('Opacity', 1, 0.5)
end;

end.
```

The Frame Code:

```
unit UObjects;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants, 
  FMX.Types, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Objects, FMX.Layouts, FMX.TreeView, FMX.Controls.Presentation,
  FMX.Memo.Types, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo, FMX.Edit, System.ImageList,
  FMX.ImgList;

type
  TFObjects = class(TFrame)
    GPanelObjects: TGridPanelLayout;
    RObjectContainer: TRectangle;
    GMain: TGridPanelLayout;
    GContainer: TGridPanelLayout;
    GDoSomthing: TGridPanelLayout;
    DoSomething_1: TRectangle;
    GridPanelLayout1: TGridPanelLayout;
    Text: TText;
    ImageList1: TImageList;
    GridPanelLayout2: TGridPanelLayout;
    Image1: TImage;
    GridPanelLayout3: TGridPanelLayout;
    DoSomthingRect_Text_1: TRectangle;
    Circle1: TCircle;
    DoSomthingRect_Text_2: TRectangle;
    Circle2: TCircle;
    DoSomthingRect_Text_3: TRectangle;
    Circle3: TCircle;
    DoSomthingRect_Text_4: TRectangle;
    Circle4: TCircle;
    Rectangle1: TRectangle;
    Rectangle6: TRectangle;
    Rectangle11: TRectangle;
    CornerButton2: TCornerButton;
    CornerButton3: TCornerButton;
    CornerButton1: TCornerButton;
    CornerButton4: TCornerButton;
    procedure CornerButton1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Single);
    procedure watch_info_objMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Single);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;


implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TFObjects.CornerButton1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Single);
var this: TCornerButton;
begin
  this:=TCornerButton(Sender);
end;

procedure TFObjects.watch_info_objMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Single);
begin
//  watch_info_obj
end;

end.
```

Style:

```
object TStyleContainer
  object TLayout
    StyleName = 'CornerButton1Style1'
    Align = Center
    Size.Width = 81.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 55.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Visible = False
    TabOrder = 93
    object TRectangle
      StyleName = 'background'
      Align = Contents
      Fill.Color = x00FFFFFF
      Locked = True
      HitTest = False
      Size.Width = 81.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 55.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      Stroke.Kind = None
      object TInnerGlowEffect
        Softness = 0.400000005960464500
        GlowColor = xFF4F4848
        Opacity = 0.899999976158142100
        Trigger = 'IsPressed=true'
        Enabled = False
      end
      object TColorAnimation
        StyleName = 'ColorAnimation1Style'
        Duration = 0.200000002980232200
        Inverse = True
        PropertyName = 'Fill.Color'
        StartValue = x00FFFFFF
        StopValue = x961E6CAC
        Trigger = 'IsMouseOver=true'
        TriggerInverse = 'IsMouseOver=false'
      end
    end
    object TGlyph
      StyleName = 'glyphstyle'
      Margins.Left = 2.000000000000000000
      Margins.Top = 4.000000000000000000
      Margins.Right = 2.000000000000000000
      Margins.Bottom = 2.000000000000000000
      Align = Center
      Size.Width = 40.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 40.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
    end
    object TText
      StyleName = 'text'
      Align = Client
      Locked = True
      HitTest = False
      Margins.Left = 5.000000000000000000
      Margins.Top = 2.000000000000000000
      Margins.Right = 5.000000000000000000
      Margins.Bottom = 2.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 71.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 51.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      TextSettings.WordWrap = False
    end
  end
  object TLayout
    StyleName = 'CornerButton7Style1'
    Align = Center
    Size.Width = 220.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 55.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Visible = False
    TabOrder = 91
    object TRectangle
      StyleName = 'background'
      Align = Contents
      Fill.Color = x00E0E0E0
      Locked = True
      HitTest = False
      Size.Width = 220.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 55.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      Stroke.Kind = None
      object TInnerGlowEffect
        Softness = 0.400000005960464500
        GlowColor = xFF4F4848
        Opacity = 0.899999976158142100
        Trigger = 'IsPressed=true'
        Enabled = False
      end
      object TColorAnimation
        StyleName = 'ColorAnimation1Style'
        Duration = 0.200000002980232200
        PropertyName = 'Fill.Color'
        StartValue = claNull
        StopValue = xFFA7A7A7
      end
    end
    object TGlyph
      StyleName = 'glyphstyle'
      Margins.Left = 2.000000000000000000
      Margins.Top = 4.000000000000000000
      Margins.Right = 2.000000000000000000
      Margins.Bottom = 2.000000000000000000
      Align = Left
      Size.Width = 16.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 16.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
    end
    object TText
      StyleName = 'text'
      Align = Client
      Locked = True
      HitTest = False
      Margins.Left = 5.000000000000000000
      Margins.Top = 2.000000000000000000
      Margins.Right = 5.000000000000000000
      Margins.Bottom = 2.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 210.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 51.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      TextSettings.FontColor = xFF5D5C5C
      TextSettings.WordWrap = False
    end
  end
  object TLayout
    StyleName = 'CButtonBlue'
    Align = Center
    Size.Width = 82.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 49.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Visible = False
    TabOrder = 92
    object TRectangle
      StyleName = 'background'
      Align = Contents
      Fill.Color = x00FFFFFF
      Locked = True
      HitTest = False
      Size.Width = 82.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 49.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      Stroke.Kind = None
      object TColorAnimation
        StyleName = 'ColorAnimation1Style'
        Duration = 0.200000002980232200
        Inverse = True
        PropertyName = 'Fill.Color'
        StartValue = x00FFFFFF
        StopValue = x961E6CAC
        Trigger = 'IsMouseOver=true'
        TriggerInverse = 'IsMouseOver=false'
      end
    end
    object TText
      StyleName = 'text'
      Align = Client
      Locked = True
      HitTest = False
      Margins.Left = 5.000000000000000000
      Margins.Top = 2.000000000000000000
      Margins.Right = 5.000000000000000000
      Margins.Bottom = 2.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 72.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 45.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      Text = 'Text'
    end
    object TGlyph
      StyleName = 'glyphstyle'
      Margins.Top = 4.000000000000000000
      Margins.Right = 2.000000000000000000
      Margins.Bottom = 2.000000000000000000
      Align = MostLeft
      Position.Y = 4.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 39.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 43.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: if you use
FMX.Types.GlobalUseGPUCanvas:=true;
that is, the problems disappear, but the visual part of the program becomes terrible (very sharp, blurry, etc.)

Comment: Some more information might be helpful.  Are you loading the frames at design time or run time?  If the latter, show us the code that you are using to do this.  And is this in Windows, Android, or what?

Comment: Show a [minimal, complete, verifiable and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
 With such example, we will be able to reproduce your problem, understand it and try to solve it.

Comment: @fpiette
I found one of the old projects in which I had the same problem. I attached the code to the theme, maybe it will help somehow
The logic of enabling frames is the same for all projects that exist
In general, nothing supernatural is used anymore.
In the style of the button there is a rectangle background with Fill - Solid -White - Alpha 0 and animation that changes color and transparency to blue when hovering

Comment: Where are the fmx and dpr files? Complete project means I can just copy it in a directory on my disk, compile, run and see what's wrong. I have no time to rebuild the missing pieces.

Comment: @fpiette I'm not sure that this is allowed here, but I attach a link to the project, I think it will be easier to figure it out.
https://github.com/Ocengrave/FrameErrEM

Comment: I've got your code. I had to change 2 lines (131 and 138 in uMain) to compile it with Delphi 11.3. Only the "home screen" (2nd button on the left) is working and I don't see anything wrong.  The 3rd button on the left only shows an empty screen and "settings" button generate an access violation.

Comment: @fpiette Do you really have no problems with styles in the code that I showed you?
I tried to run on versions 10.4 and 11.2 and I have the same problem as described in the topic, the borders of the buttons appear until you hover over them or the size of the form is changed.
I do not know if my hardware somehow affects this, but I tested it on RTX 2070 super / RTX 3050 in conjunction with Ryzen 5 3500x

Comment: @fpiette In any case, I am grateful to you for trying to help me solve the problem, it's very nice.

Comment: I can't say more than what I already said. And please notice I'm using the latest Delphi: 11.3.

Comment: @fpiette Well, thank you. I noticed one point that if you make all the parameters false in the button in the Sides property, then the problem is partially solved. However, this does not always fix the problem

Comment: Do the artifacts appear when you make sure the components are positioned on integer value positions (trunc'ed singles or whole numbers)? I'm experiencing the same problem with Bitmap-filled Rectangles that are not positioned on integer-value positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 10.4.2 and running your example program, I reproduced the problem that I believe that you are describing, on the three buttons in the frame.

I couldn't find what was causing it, and like you I tried `Repaint` and a few other things.

However, I did find a workaround.  Your example had the frame's `Align:=TAlignLayout.Client;` after putting in its container (`RInsideContainer`).  As long as that is always the case, the following should work without unwanted side effects.

Just before the end of the `.OpenFrame` method, I added the following lines:

```
  CurrentWorkFrame.Width:=CurrentWorkFrame.Width+1;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  CurrentWorkFrame.Width:=CurrentWorkFrame.Width-1;
```

It seems that even though the `Align` prevents the size from changing, it *does* trigger some sort of repaint that removes the button's borders before they are seen.

Comment: Thank you, I did a little differently to fix this error, but I think your method is more interesting. I make a small pop-up menu that was causing a redraw, then this problem disappeared.

Comment: Another way is to do the same thing with the form as a whole, but unless the form is maximised, you do actually see some flicker with the width adjusting and adjusting back again, which is why I think that adjusting the frame's width is the better option.  And yes, there could be several other ways to trigger a redraw.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Application.ProcessMessages;
CurrentWorkFrame.BringToFront;
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone out there has this issue, I'm sure that even with the latest version of Firemonkey (11.3), you've tried all of the above with varying results..

I've been tracking this same problem in many of my Firemonkey apps and it seems to happen when Styles are used on Panels (worst) or edits (more options to address), inside a TFrame. If I can make any point is that you, @OceanGrave, have a valid problem here. There is definitely artefacts left behind after said panels are shown or hidden, or text has been changed in edit boxes. With OPAGUE styles, when inside a Frame.

Depending on the Component, here's some stuff to try in your own project if you also encounter this:

*After showing or hiding panels, repaint the panel, and then the frame.*

```
pnl.repaint;
self.repaint;
```

*If you get artefacts after changing text in an edit box or combobox:*
This will sound crazy, and is definitely not how I usually do things, but after you've changed all the text in all the edit boxes on your Frame, enable a timer set at an interval of 10 with OnTimer that first disables the timer itself, then repaints the current frame.. For some reason, this works well with user interactive controls like edits and combos, but only sometimes with the panels..

I also tried things like *FMX.Types.GlobalUseGPUCanvas:=true;* which is horrendously ugly, but actually fixes the problem too.. But I'm not sure if that's just because it couldn't draw those artefacts in the first place or not.

Setfocus() on the edit also seems to make some difference..

Playing with Positions, widths and heights of objects (adjusting and then reverting to trigger a redraw) sees mixed results.

When trying different things, watch out when using *Application.Processmessages* <- This is not your friend and might cause more additional input problems for edits when called at OnEnter or OnExit..

I'm not sure how Embarcadero has their Great IDE out and sometimes I get to deal with wild goose chases and "Tape It Shut" fixes in my professional application. This just wastes precious time...

Comment: Still battling with this...

Additional:
https://github.com/skia4delphi/skia4delphi/releases/tag/v6.0.0

Use Skia4Delphi for graphics rendering, which never seem to cause the artefacts anywhere, however this might cause further strange graphics with aliasing on text..